# Shorten titles in simple pie

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, feed

I want to display a list of post from a non wordpress website to my wordpress website using RSS. I want to show a thumbnail, short desc, link, title and style them.

I found this http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/shorten_titles_and_descriptions which works for limiting desc amount, I am still wondering how I can shorten `TITLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
echo shorten($item->get_title(), 100);
```

Comment: Thank you, but still its not working correctly, it gives random number of word. I wanted to display exact 100 Words everytime. But doin this, it shows random number of words? Any Help?

Comment: Are you used non-ascii for your title ?

`shorten` has used substr, you can replace with mb_substr http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php